# A little confusion with the sorted function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

```
sorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
sorted xs = and [x <= y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]
```

Can anyone explain to me what this random `and` is doing after `=`? It works when I compile it but it doesn't make logical sense to me. Is it because Haskell works recursively and it uses the `and` to compare the next item?

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a function `pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]` is defined somewhere, the expression

```
[x <= y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]
```

is a list of a booleans (that is, its type is `[Bool]`). [`and`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/base/Prelude.html#v:and) is a function whose type is `[Bool] -> Bool`: It takes a list of booleans and it gives back `True` if all of the booleans in the list are `True` and `False` otherwise.

`and [x <= y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]` is a function application (`and` is being applied to the value created by the list comprehension).

One thing to note is that Haskell doesn't have a lot of special keywords, comparatively. Many operations are represented by functions rather than by special syntax or keywords.

Answer (score 1):

`and` is not the function for taking the logical-and of two boolean values; that's `&&` (with type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`).

Instead `and` has type `[Bool] -> Bool`; it condenses an arbitrary number of boolean values down to a single one by "anding them all".